# Uploading image is not creating media file

Tags: django, django-models

Guys I'm new to django I tried uploading images in the imagefield but it's not creating media folder and the database image column is also blank.

**settings.py**

```
MEDIA_ROOT =  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media') 

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

**models.py**

```
class Profile(models.Model): 

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50) 

    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
```

**image.html**

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data>
{% csrf_token %}
<input type="file" class="form-control" id="customFile" name="image"/></div>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="">
    </div>
</form>
```

**views.py**

```
def hotel:
    if request.method == "POST" :
                post=Profile()
                post.image= request.POST.get('image')
                post.name = request.POST.get('name')
                post.save()
                return redirect('/vendor_dashboard/profile_pic')
    return render(request,'profile.html')
```

Even tried manually creating the media file Django.

Still nothing!!

Any help Will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You have to include {{form.media}} to the django form template if you want to post any type of media to django

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form- 
data>

{% csrf_token %}

{{form.media}}

<input type="file" class="form-control" 
idd="customFile" name="image"/></div>
<input type="text" class="form-control" 
name="name" placeholder="">
</div>
</form>
```

edit:
and in views.py you have to use request.FILES to get any media file(forgot to mention this)

```
request.FILES.get('image')
```

and to get the image from media use .url

```
{% Profileobject.image.url %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Uploaded files are in `request.FILES` instead of `request.POST`. So your file handling should look like this:

```py
# post.image= request.POST.get('image')
post.image = request.FILES['image']
```

I'd recommend to read the [Django docs about file uploads](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/file-uploads/)

Answer (score 0):

use `request.FILES`:

```
def hotel:
        if request.method == "POST" :
                post=Profile()
                post.image= request.FILES['image']
                post.name = request.POST.get('name')
                post.save()
                return redirect('/vendor_dashboard/profile_pic')
        return render(request,'profile.html')
```

Comment: How to view the image ?

Comment: you can check your media folder or on your template use `<img src="{{object.image.url}}" />`